# iPad app documents folder

Tags: xcode, backup, ios, documents

Is there a way to tell iTunes not to backup the contents of the apps documents folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10) of Apple's documentation. The folder `Documents/` is automatically backed up. If you don't want a file to be backed up, you need to put it in either `Library/Caches/` or `tmp/`.

You can't change behavior of apps if you don't have the source code of the app.

Comment: I have the source code for the app. The app stores lots of pdf files in the documents directory. What I was hoping for was to give the user a setting to allow them to backup the contents of the documents fodler or not. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: No. But you can save the PDF files in the `Library/Caches/` or `Documents/` depending on the user setting.

Comment: I have seen an app that does this. Im guessing that when a user toggle the backup value it moves the documents from caches to documents and vice versa.